# Создание блоков в kivymd

Tags: python, sqlite3, kivy

Делаю приложение на python, котрое взаимодействует в SQLite добавляя или выводя записи (значения)

Прошёл через русских, английских, индуских блогеров, но не нашёл решения или примера, как созлавать блоки со значениями. Везде статическое всё.

Допустим есть таблица с фамилией, именем, возрастом и краткой информацией. Нужно, чтобы в заранее созданый шаблон блока добавлялись значения и выводиличь на экран несколько блока

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как оказалось очень просто. Создаём метод, который возвращает необходимые блоки. Можно в качестве параметров принимать значения, которые необходимо вставить.

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def CreateBox(self):
        bl = MDBoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=10)
        bl.add_widget(MDLabel(text="Hello, World", halign="center"))
        bl.add_widget(Button(text="Hello, World", pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}))
        bl.add_widget(MDLabel(text="Hello, World", halign="center"))
        return bl


    def build(self):
        gl = GridLayout(cols=3, padding=10)
        for i in range(10):
            gl.add_widget(self.CreateBox())
        return gl

MainApp().run()
```

А ещё я немного пошаманил и цикл перенёс в метод, который принимает количество итераций(блоков), так же можно передавать массив данных.

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def CreateBox(self, number_blocks=3):
        big_layout = GridLayout(cols = 3, padding=10)
        for i in range(number_blocks):
            bl = MDBoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=10)
            text_widgets = "Hello, World" + str(i)
            bl.add_widget(MDLabel(text=text_widgets, halign="center"))
            bl.add_widget(Button(text=text_widgets, pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}))
            bl.add_widget(MDLabel(text=text_widgets, halign="center"))
            big_layout.add_widget(bl)
        return big_layout

    def build(self):
        bl = GridLayout(cols=3, padding=10)
        bl.add_widget(self.CreateBox(10))
        return bl

MainApp().run()
```

Фото итога последней версии

[image: Фото итога последней версии]